# How to specify --insecure option of curl when using python requests package

Tags: python-2.7, curl, python-requests

I have a curl command where I use `--insecure` option. How do I use the same when using python requests package?

Comment: Very bad strategy; see [The most dangerous code in the world: validating SSL certificates in non-browser software](http://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/pubs/abstracts/ssl-client-bugs.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests
requests.get('https://www.acme.com', verify=False)
```